# Array keeps counting 0 as a number when I didn'

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a game show program where I enter the number of contestants, how fast they hit the buzzer, the fastest and slowest times for hitting the buzzer, and the number of people that hit the buzzer faster than average.

Everything goes well with my program when I have 5 contestants. But if I enter 4 contestants or anything else less than 5, it messes up some things. When I have 4 contestants, my fastest time is 0, even when I'm not putting in a 0 as a time, and the number of contestants that hit the buzzer faster than average is also messed up, having one extra than it should, because it's putting in a 0.

How do I stop this program from adding in a 0 when I don't have 5 contestants?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FastestFingers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            //declare varialbes
        int contestants;
        int [] milisecs = new int [6];

        int fastest, slowest, i;
        int faster = 0;
        double average;

        Scanner scanInt = new Scanner (System.in);

        //make user enter number of contestants


                System.out.println ("Enter # of contestants: ");
                contestants = scanInt.nextInt();
        //make user enter times
        for(i=1;i<=contestants;i++)
            {
                System.out.println ("Time (ms): ");
                milisecs[i] = scanInt.nextInt();
            }
        //calculate fastest time
        fastest = milisecs[1];
                for(i=1;i<milisecs.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(milisecs[i] < fastest)
                            {
                                fastest = milisecs[i];
                            }
                    }
        System.out.println ("Fastest: " + fastest);
        //calculate slowest time
        slowest = milisecs[1];
                for(i=1;i<milisecs.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(milisecs[i] > slowest)
                            {
                                slowest = milisecs[i];
                            }
                    }
                    System.out.println ("Slowest: " + slowest);
        //tell program how to find average
        int total = 0;
        for(i=1;i<milisecs.length;i++)
            {
                total = total + milisecs[i];
            }
        average = total/contestants;
        //find numbers faster than the average
        int count = 0;
        for(i=1;i<milisecs.length;i++)
            {
                if(milisecs[i]<average)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
            }
        System.out.println ("Faster than average: " + count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You create an `int[]` of fixed size 6. Then you compare the last 5 values to find the lowest. All `int` values are default 0. If you only set 4 values to anything larger than 0 the fifth value will always be 0 and therefore your lowest value.

You can fix this problem by setting the size of your array to the number of contestants.

---

Also remember that arrays start counting at 0 not at 1. Your loops should therefore be:

`for(i=0;i<milisecs.length;i++)`, etc.

Comment: But wouldn't that affect the numbers when I have 5 players? Or 3? Or 2? Is there a way I can make it so I can have any number of contestants and still have the program work correctly?

Comment: What specifically? If you have an array with size == numberOfContestants you will not have any issues as long as the number of contestants is a valid integer value > 0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you initialize the array to have six elements.

```
int [] milisecs = new int [6];
```

By default all of these values will be zero. Then in your loop you only initialize four of them, meaning that two will still be zero. Change your code to:

```
System.out.println ("Enter # of contestants: ");
contestants = scanInt.nextInt();
int [] milisecs = new int [contestants];
```

This will ensure that you will only have as many time slots as you have contestants.

Also array indexes start at zero, so you should change

```
fastest = milisecs[1];
```

to

```
fastest = milisecs[0];
```

And in your loops, start your variable at 0 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Array Index should start with 0. Please be careful with this. You code reads input and assigns to the `milisecs` starting from index 1.